# Does connecting to a VPN always provide a secure environment over unencrypted WiFI connections?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, vpn, encryption

Sometimes I have to use public WiFi connections. I always connect to a VPN thinking it will provide the security of encryption.

However, I don't know any details about how the VPN I use is implemented, so have some uncertainty. Do VPNs always alleviate the dangers of using insecure WiFI connections?

Comment: The tunnel itself should be OK and impenetrable. A problem with some VPNs is the initial authentication. One of the MSCHAP/CHAP (I think) has been proved that credentials can be obtained prior to the tunnel being created. You don't mention what VPN technology you use... PPTP, SSTP, OpenVPN etc.

Comment: @BigChris Thanks, that's where I was noticing a problem. Is there any way to find out the handshake on my own? Could you write an answer about the ones with concerns? I think that should answer it.

Comment: I don't think an answer I provide would be suitable because of the vast number of resources on the Internet that go into great detail as to the pros and cons of different VPN technologies. A quick search has found this URL: https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/4147/pptp-vs-l2tp-vs-openvpn-vs-sstp-vs-ikev2/ which goes over some of the differences. Because you haven't written what VPN technology you use it's difficult for us to provide an answer that isn't going to be long winded and cover many different possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As @BigChris said, The VPN should be OK once the tunnel is up, but only if the host servers are actually secure, and haven't got malware or bugs in the OS.

Rule of thumb: if you think a hotspot is insecure, it probably is. If you have mobile data available, use the hotspot function on your phone to create a temporary connection, connect to the VPN, then, within about 30 seconds, connect, or switch to the insecure network. TCP will maintain a grace period of retries in which you can use to connect, while staying secure.